# GCMBroadcastReceiver not fired

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have library project that is using GCM. I am trying to use not deprecated way without gcm.jar. Let's start from manifest of application project (not library):

Here I have package set

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sennin.app"
```

Here I create my permission:

```
<permission android:name="com.sennin.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

And here I use it with others:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sennin.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is receiver and IntentService entry:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.sennin.app.SenninGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
     <category android:name="com.sennin.app" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.sennin.app.GCMIntentService" />
```

I know that receiver action `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` is in theory redundant but this is hack to make registration work with older devices (found on stackoverflow by the way).

I need to add that my library has package `com.sennin`.

Ok now let's go to the receiver itself:

```
public class SenninGCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("GCM", "RECEIVE GCM");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

In first line onReceive method is, as you can see `Log`. This log is important and all I want is to see this log in `logcat`;)

I omitted registration part of messaging process because registration is working well. I have `registration_id` I send it to server. On the server site I put `registration_id` to datastore. After that I am just trying to send some messages. I can see on server side that message was sent. I have message_id and no errors. Everything seems to be just well, but receiver never get called. I want to see this log in `onReceive()` method but it's never happen.

Is there any obvious mistake? Maybe I just don't wanna find it;)

I want just add that I have been tested it on Android 2.3 and Android 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your library's package is com.sennin,  but in the manifest you have  com.sennin.app in the declaration of the receiver and service. Which one is it.  A mismatch may explain your problem, since the receiver declared in the manifest doesn't exist and therefore can't be started.

Comment: Yes but as I said: "Let's start from manifest of application project (not library)". This is manifest of application not library project. This app is using library project which provide all functionality with GCM as well. But application has own GCMIntentService and own GCMBroadcastReceiver...

Comment: @sennin Then how is the library project used by the app? Is the package of `SenninGCMBroadcastReceiver` `com.sennin` or `com.sennin.app`?

Comment: In fact I simplified this a little in above entry. `SenninGCMBroadcastReceiver` (which is in application) derives `GCMBroadcastReceiver` (which is in library) and the last one derives `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. So in application manifest I have `com.sennin.app.SenninGCMBroadcastReceiver` because this is exact path of this class.

Comment: @sennin In that case, it would help if you post the current code of both `SenninGCMBroadcastReceiver` and `GCMBroadcastReceiver`.